# android variables not incrementing inside loop

Tags: java, android, loops, operators, increment

I am trying to write a simple android program that will print the lyrics to 99 bottles of beer on the wall in the following format.

Line 1: 99 bottles of beer on the wall...

Line 2: 98 bottles of beer on the wall...

and so on.

I am trying to make a loop that will print the first line of lyrics, then increment/decrement the variables "lineNumber", "numOfBottles", and "lessNumOfBottles".

I've tried a few different methods and operators but my variables never change when compiled and I get the same repeating numbers every line of lyrics.

What am I doing wrong? (the bottom loop in comments is the first one I've tried and I've only left it as reference for myself)

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();


    int lineNumber = 1;
    int numOfBottles = 99;
    int lessNumOfBottles = 98;
    String line = "Line " + lineNumber + ":\n";
    String lyrics= "Lyrics to 99 bottles of beer \n\n";
    String song =line +  numOfBottles + " bottles of beer on the wall," + numOfBottles + " bottles of beer, take one down, pass it around," + lessNumOfBottles + " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";


    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    textview.setText(lyrics);

    for(int i = 99;i >= 1;i--) {
        if (numOfBottles >= 1) {
            textview.append(song);
            --numOfBottles;
            --lessNumOfBottles;
            ++lineNumber;
        }
    }

    /*for (int i=0;i<99;){
        lineNumber++;
        numOfBottles= --numOfBottles;
        lessNumOfBottles= --lessNumOfBottles;
        textview.setText(song);
        textview.append(song);
        i++;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: yes, they are ... but it is not showing ... as **you blocked main thread** and there is no time to redraw the screen between incrementation ...

Comment: @Selvin, even though he's blocking the main thread, after the loop executes, the fact that he is incrementing his variables won't matter since it won't change the outcome of his `String`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the value of the String only once, to the first value of `lineNumber`, `numOfBottles`, and `lessNumOfBottles`. The `line` and `song` variables are never updated.

Try this instead:

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();


    int numLines = 100;
    int numOfBottles = 99;
    String line;
    String lyrics= "Lyrics to 99 bottles of beer \n\n";

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    textview.setText(lyrics);

    for(int i = numOfBottles;i >= 1;i--) {
        if (numOfBottles >= 1) {
            line = "Line " + numLines-i + ":\n";
            textview.append(line + i + " bottles of beer on the wall," + 
                             i + " bottles of beer, take one down, pass it around," + 
                             i-1 + " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I was assuming that due to the string variables being declared by adding the values to them, every time the string was called it was being re-declared. I see where I was wrong, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I can see where you were confused. I added a possible solution to help you on your way.